# Why isn't log4j2 printing anything to the screen?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm trying to configure log4j2 with the following file:

### log4j2.properties

```
# Global logging settings
name = LoggingConfig
status = trace
dest = err

property.logDir = /logs/my_project
property.pattern = [%-level - %logger] %date{DEFAULT}%n Thread: %threadName%n%message%n

# stdout logger
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = ${pattern}

# File logger
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = File
appender.file.fileName = ${logDir}/api.log
appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern = ${pattern}

# Root logger
rootLogger.level = trace
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

This file is in the classpath: `src/main/resources/log4j2.properties`

But when I run my main class, it doesn't log anything. Here's the snippet I'm using:

### MyProject.java

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

class MyProject {
    private static MyController controller;
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyProject.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ctrl = new MyController();
        // Start QuickFIX/J engine
        ctrl.start();

        logger.info("Controller started. Loading the API.");

        // Start Spring ...
    }
```

I read the [official documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties) and implemented it to the best of my understanding and yet I can't find a way to make it work.

### Gradle Dependencies

```
compile 'org.quickfixj:quickfixj-all:1.6.2'
compile 'org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.0.13'

compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.3.RELEASE') {
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:1.4.1.RELEASE'

compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:2.7'

compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.1.Final'
compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1209'
```

---

### Questions

Am I configuring and using log4j2 wrong?
Are my dependencies screwing up log4j2 somehow?

Comment: I gave up trying to use a .properties file with log4j2 myself. I switched to XML and that worked a lot better.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. .propeties file does seem second class in the docs and blog posts. Is .xml better supported?

Comment: This works fine for me.

Comment: For the sake of the example, get rid of the file appender and the Spring Boot pieces.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'll edit it. I wanted to emphasize the Spring dependency thinking it could be a culprit. This example runs fine on its own. But when I mix all the dependencies listed, it stops...

Comment: Let me recreate it all then. What is `MyController`? Does that interfere?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It is the program's entry-point. It is the main method for Spring. It also starts the QuickFIX engine to process incoming network calls that implement the FIX protocol. Nasty stuff.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a real [mcve]?

Comment: I'll try as soon as I get on a computer. Might be just tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the configuration that made it all work:

### log4j2.properties

I was missing logger configuration that uses the appenders:

```
logger.file.name = MyProject
logger.file.level = info
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = File
```

### build.gradle dependencies

```
compile 'org.quickfixj:quickfixj-all:1.6.2'
compile 'org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.0.16'

compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.5.RELEASE') {
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}

compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.6'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.6'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:2.6'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.6'

compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.4.Final'
compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1209'
```

The Spring Boot log4j2 plugin doesn't work for other packages. So I removed it and added the `log4j2` dependencies declaratively instead. This way Spring, Hibernate, Mina, QuickFIX/J, etc., can log properly.

*Note*: At the time of this answer, Spring is only compatible with `log4j2` version 2.6 and below, higher versions changed the API and Spring didn't make the appropriate changes yet.

Answer (score -1):

Dependency-wise, you can try adding log4j-api and log4j-core to ensure the version matches that of the log4j-web dependency.

Your configuration looks correct except that the File appender is not referenced by any logger so it will not receive any events.

I notice that the configuration has `status=trace`, this should result in Log4j initialization logs being printed to the console. If you're not seeing that, the problem precedes the place where Log4j initializes from the configuration file.

To switch on status logging from the very beginning, set system property `-Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=TRACE`. What do you see if you add that?

Comment: Both `log4j-api` and `log4j-code` get pulled in by `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` already.

Comment: What version does spring-boot pull in? 2.7?

Comment: I'm using "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.3.RELEASE"

Comment: Do you also see the problem when you remove the log4-web dependency?

Comment: Yes. It's presence doesn't affect the outcome other than an annoying warning.